# Search for files that are NOT a specific kind on my Mac

Tags: macos, spotlight, font, search, postscript

I am trying to work out which fonts I have on my machine that are Type 1 Postscript fonts so I can avoid problems when Adobe stops supporting them next year. I have used kind:”type 1 outline font” which shows all of them but as I have so many fonts it might be quicker to identify those that are NOT Type 1 fonts! Can anyone help with the search string I should use please.

Comment: Fontbook will do this. Select all fonts (top left) and search for postscript type1. It will list all your type 1 fonts. You can search on **ANY** "Kind" of font, TrueType, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Font Book to search for the PS Type 1 fonts.

In the *Search* bar, click the dropdown and select "Kind" as shown below.  Enter "Type 1".

[image: Font Book Search Field]

Any fonts that match, will be in "normal" text.  Those that don't will be greyed out.

[image: Font Book Search Results Screen]

From here, you can disable the font or *Show in Finder* (right click) so you can manually manipulate the file.

Answer (score 0):

TrueType and OpenType fonts will have file extensions: .`ttf`, `.ttc`, or `.otf`. (Also `.dfont`.)

A <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> search in the Finder for 'TrueType' will list all the TrueType fonts in the Search hierarchy.

The Same for 'OpenType'. You can combine the two by Alt-clicking on the + button to create multiple criteria.

[image]

Type 1 PostScript printer fonts will usually not have any extension -- the screen bitmaps also might not, or they might have .suit or .bmap. As a consequence, their 'type' may not be recognised by Launch Services and Spotlight, even though they are actively enabled in the OS.

Apple now refers to Type 1 fonts as 'legacy format', which is always a worrying designation.

Comment: 1) Can just use kind:font in search box. 2) Need system files included to get all fonts.

Comment: @Gilby Won't that include T1 fonts? IF the OP is trying to remove T1 fonts, they're not going to be in System folders -- and if they are, then removing the TT and OTF first won't work.

Comment: I have Type 1 fonts which are system files. Rereading the question I am confused: how can finding non type1 fonts help the OP tidy up the Type 1 fonts?

Comment: @Gilby OS X has not contained Type 1 fonts in /System or /Library since Tiger, if not ever. Presumably, they are extracting the TT / OTF fonts, and then deleting the rest.