# List available serif fonts

Tags: font

I have been trying to find a way to locate suitable fonts for a book project. For the purposes of this question, I want to find all the fonts I have available on my Mac which

1. are serif fonts, and
2. have particular font features (e.g., Old Style Figures).

With regards to the second issue, using `otfinfo` on the command line, I can determine which fonts have a given feature (in my example, any ones which have 'onum' among the features).

But, as for the first, I have been looking at `fc-list` and the like, but it's not clear to me what I should be passing either it, or an alternate command, to determine whether a font is a serif font.

Is that even possible? I.e., is there any internal encoding to that effect, or is it strictly a matter of visual inspection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for files that are NOT a specific kind on my Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440239/search-for-files-that-are-not-a-specific-kind-on-my-mac)

Comment: @Allan Not that I can see... My Font Book doesn't seem to have a 'kind' drop-down, but from what I can see from the other example, even if it did, it wouldn't get me what I need (serif info).

Comment: Style or Family don’t have what you want?

Comment: Appartenly there is a command, `fc-match` that allows you to check if a font is a serif font: `fc-match -s serif fontname`. I couldn't get it to work on my Mac though. If that doesn't work, maybe I need to think about a Python script with the `fontTools` library.

Comment: The only other way that comes to mind on how to find serif fonts is by creating a new smart collection from within the Font Book app. In there set "Design Style" "is" "Serif". The fact that Font Book *can* filter by design style says that this information is stored somewhere in the font file, but million dollar question is how...

Comment: @Allan Could be I'm not understanding how to do that in a helpful way, I'm totally new to this. @Alex Thanks, I had the idea of filtering in a new collection, I just couldn't figure out how to get it to do what I want, which may be what @Allan was also suggesting. I'll look at it again. I also thought of a Python script, just hadn't looked into that yet (more work!) but maybe I will. As for `fc-match` and company, the documentation I found (man pages etc.) wasn't tremendously helpful in saying what to put in the various places other than a vague 'elements' and so on!! I will try some more!

Comment: Addendum. I tried the smart collection, setting design style to serif (I missed that somehow when I first tried it before posting!!) and that 'works' in the sense that it creates a list, but some of the items in there are definitely NOT serif--suggesting badly coded files. And, creating a smart collection for sans-serif does have some serif items as well. Guess for perfect results, visual inspection will be required to be totally safe!

Comment: While some Pro sans fonts will have alternative numeral styles; you probably won't find many Std sans fonts with them. So if you're making a list from which you're going to make a choice anyway, I'd just use oftinfo to get all fonts with onum.

Comment: Addendum 2. `fc-match -s serif` by itself did generate a list of fonts with Times New Roman at the top of the list (without -s, it's the only result). Subject to the accuracy of font coding, this is likely what I need as I can pipe the results and extract what I need from there. I'll compare the list with visual inspection and see how that pans out... then likely we can close the question. Thanks, both.

Comment: @benwiggy I actually tried that yesterday. It turns out that some fonts have Old Style figures even when not marked with `onum`. Looks like one can use any of the approaches mentioned here for 'rough' results, but will have to do it the hard way to be comprehensive or sure.

Comment: TBH, I would only use non-lining figures on traditional Humanist or Transitional typefaces anyway: so Minion, Garamond, Caslon, Baskerville; but not a Century or Didone. And I would choose the face for the book first, and then decide whether I was going to use non-lining figs or not! For page numbers, probably not. But this is probably something for GraphicDesign SE....

Comment: @benwiggy I agree. For my purposes, which is to affect a somewhat older style, I want old style figures for sure, and I've pretty much ruled out anything later than Baskerville (and on that one I'm not fussy on the italic, which does matter). Maybe Bembo (looking at ETBookOT maybe for short term, purchase later, but not done with the research yet)! But now I'm beyond my original question :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see after some experimentation, the strict answer to my questions is, can't really be done. A more pragmatic answer would be, 'can be done after a fashion, but not perfectly'.

With respect to #2 (font features), `otfinfo` obviously does list fonts with particular special features, but if the question is (as it was in my case), which font has old style figures, then only fonts which have them as an Open Type feature will be listed; fonts whose default figures are old style will not be captured; this has to be inspected manually. (Not really suprising but a potential pit for the unwary.)

As for #1, the various suggestions given here will *tend* to yield the desired response, but it turns out that (e.g.) fonts internally identified by feature as serif may not be *and* vice versa.

The only way to be absolutely comprehensive seems to be by visual inspection.

(I have learned that font classification is quite complicated--rather like trying to make a continuous variable onto a discrete one--though one might expect the presence or absence of serifs to be straightforward. Apparently, it isn't!

And for the record, this is true though font files are obtained reputably, i.e., via major vendor apps and the like.